# Xamarin Android Simulator launching forever

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.4.5) & its default emulator for Android device.
I just try to run simple hello world of Xamarin Form. When I click to Debug [image]

It's has just launch the Android Device, and stucking at it's forever, no deploy and Visual Studio's progress bar is always running... I have waiting more than 16 hours. 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? What version are you targeting and what's the minimum version?

Comment: Although not an actual solution to this problem, but you may want to look at Genymotion as an alternative. It's free for personal use and works way better.

Answer (score 2):

After all, I found a solution,

Open Regedit, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node node,
Create a new key named '**Android SDK Tools**', create a variable name **Path**, the value point to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk'
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- enable Hyper-V
- install Intel HAXM Drivers
- use x86 system images
- enable Host GPU
- Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)

https://university.xamarin.com/resources/working-with-android-emulators

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/google-emulator-manager?tabs=vswin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/visual-studio-android-emulator